# How can I prevent Linux Mint from automatically responding to an external monitor being plugged in and attempting to change my display settings?

Tags: linux-mint, kde

**Background:**

HDMI Support for my Precision M4800 has always been a bit questionable, but now I've got myself into a strange place. If I unplug my HDMI cable, my laptop screen goes blank - even though I've first disabled the external monitor. Everything works fine as long as the HDMI is plugged in, even if I don't use the second monitor.

I'm in a pinch and need a quick work around. If there were a way to make windows manager not automatically attempt to adjust my monitor settings when a Video (hdmi or vga) cable is plugged in - or un plugged in my case, I could at least I think get in a place where I could operate my laptop stand-alone and go from there.

**Question:** How can I prevent Linux Mint from automatically responding to an external monitor being plugged in and attempting to change my display settings?

System: Linux Mint 17.3, Dell Precision M4800